# How to change one Excel cell value using python and read a column values related to this cell with formula?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I should iterate the value of a cell in an Excel file, lets say A5 from 1 to 100

and for each value, I should read the values of a column like C1 to C10 that are related  to the value of A5 by a formula.

I wanted to know, should I change the value in A5 and save and close the file and re open and read it or there is a better way to do so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ 
I am using this module and dont have to close the file to check other cells after i edit another.